# Fast way to add Controls to a TableLayoutPanel

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, tablelayoutpanel

I have to add a lot of `Control` objects to a [`TableLayoutPanel`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.windows.forms.tablelayoutpanel%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) dynamically, what takes a significant amount of time. I also need to be able to access the controls via row- and column-index of the `TableLayoutPanel` and vice versa.

`TableLayoutPanel.Controls` has (as far as I know) 3 ways to add `Control` objects:

- `.Add(Control)` - inherited, position is -1,-1 with `.GetCellPosition(Control)`
- `.Add(Control, column, row)` - position and indexes are correct, but maybe a bit slow?
- `.AddRange (Control[])` - inherited, faster, shown position is correct (every cell is filled, if necessary columnspans are set afterwards), but position is -1,-1 with `.GetCellPosition(Control)`

Is there a way to combine the advantages of `.Add(Control, column, row` and `.AddRange(Control[])`, i.e. to add a lot of `Control`objects fast to a `TableLayoutPanel` while still being able to get the position of a `Control` programmatically?

---

**EDIT** to include some information from the comments:

- There are up to 1000 controls added
- I already use `SuspendLayout()` and `ResumeLayout()`
- The `TableLayoutPanel` takes about 2 seconds to load. According to the profiler roughly 50% of the time is spent with adding Controls, 20% with `ResumeLayout()`

---

**EDIT: MCVE**
My original code is more complex, but this is an example of a `TableLayoutPanel` where adding the controls takes most of the time spent (2/3). I am searching for a way to speed this up.

```
public class FormTLPTest : Form
{
    public FormTLPTest()
    {
        Height = 800;
        Width = 800;

        TableLayoutPanel tlp = new TableLayoutPanel();
        tlp.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
        tlp.CellBorderStyle = TableLayoutPanelCellBorderStyle.Single;
        tlp.AutoScroll = true;

        Controls.Add(tlp);

        tlp.ColumnCount = 7;
        tlp.ColumnStyles.Add(new ColumnStyle(SizeType.Absolute, 20));
        tlp.ColumnStyles.Add(new ColumnStyle(SizeType.Percent, 100.0F));
        tlp.ColumnStyles.Add(new ColumnStyle(SizeType.Absolute, 80));
        tlp.ColumnStyles.Add(new ColumnStyle(SizeType.Absolute, 100));
        tlp.ColumnStyles.Add(new ColumnStyle(SizeType.Absolute, 30));
        tlp.ColumnStyles.Add(new ColumnStyle(SizeType.Absolute, 70));
        tlp.ColumnStyles.Add(new ColumnStyle(SizeType.Absolute, 20));

        tlp.SuspendLayout();

        for (int i = 0; i<700; i++)
        {
            Button btn1 = new Button();
            Label lb2 = new Label();
            Label lb3 = new Label();
            Label lb4 = new Label();
            TextBox tb5 = new TextBox();
            Button btn6 = new Button();
            Button btn7 = new Button();

            foreach (Control c in new Control[] { btn1, lb2, lb3, lb4, tb5, btn6, btn7})
            {
                c.Margin = new Padding();
                c.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
                c.BackColor = Color.White;
            }

            btn1.FlatStyle = FlatStyle.Flat;
            btn6.FlatStyle = FlatStyle.Flat;
            btn7.FlatStyle = FlatStyle.Flat;

            btn1.Text = "1";
            lb2.Text = "Some longer Text - it contains information. Don't know what I should write to fill the space";
            lb3.Text = "Short Text";
            lb4.Text = "Short Text";
            tb5.Text = "5";
            btn6.Text = "Button";
            btn7.Text = "+";

            tlp.Controls.Add(btn1, 0, i);
            tlp.Controls.Add(lb2, 1, i);
            tlp.Controls.Add(lb3, 2, i);
            tlp.Controls.Add(lb4, 3, i);
            tlp.Controls.Add(tb5, 4, i);
            tlp.Controls.Add(btn6, 5, i);
            tlp.Controls.Add(btn7,6, i);
        }

        tlp.ResumeLayout();
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you suspend the layout before adding? Usually redrawing is the problem.

Comment: Did you use a profiler to check where the performance is lost in? I have done extensive work trying to optimize the TLP and usually it is not the panel.

Comment: Hmm, not sure if all controls have their layouting disabled. Not sure otherwise what could help.

Comment: Did you suspend the panel too?

Comment: How much is "a lot of `Control` objects"? Even if you suspend layout, adding thousands of controls is significant job (proved by profiler, 4/5 time is adding time, that should be a lot of controls to add). Even if you use [`Add(Control[])`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/Control.cs,7adf34cd6cb03c20,references) overload it's not going to be faster (they both call same `Add(Control)` method), unless `SetColumn`/`SetRow` are expensive (I don't think so, it's simple dictionary operations).

Comment: And what is the *time* we are talking about? Why is it a concern? I suspect you are expecting something wrong, like being able to refresh a complete TLP several times a second or? If you call `SuspendLayout()` and then `ResultLayout()` then you already done everything from your side regarding performance. 20% less could be ok for missing `SetColumn`/`SetRow`.

Comment: It would be better if you construct [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) first and show it. Then it is very easy to see problem and feel it or simply say "it's ok, you have to live with it" or maybe offer another design solution. You mentioned scrolling. I don't see how scrolling is related to adding (unless you add dynamically?).

Comment: If you look at [Reference Source](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/Control.cs,7adf34cd6cb03c20), you'll see that `AddRange` is nothing more than `Add` loop enclosed with `Suspend/ResumeLayout`

Comment: @IvanStoev didn't know about that, thank you. As it is a fitting answer to the question asked in my question text I will accept it if you make one out of it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looking at the [Reference Source](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/Control.cs,7adf34cd6cb03c20), you can see that `Control.ControlCollection.AddRange` method is nothing more than a `Add` loop enclosed in `SuspendLayout` / `ResumeLayout`. Since your code is also enclosed with such calls, there should not be a difference in the performance.

`TableLayoutPanel` does two additional calls - [SetRow](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.tablelayoutpanel.setrow(v=vs.110).aspx) and [SetColumn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.tablelayoutpanel.setcolumn(v=vs.110).aspx), so my first thought was that they are the slow parts. However, looking at the the source code (and measuring the time with or w/o those calls), when the layout engine is suspended, their affect on the performance are negligible.

I did some additional tests with your `mcve` by not using `TableLayoutPanel` at all and just adding controls to the form itself. The conclusion is - you just have too many controls. `mcve` is creating 4900 controls. This is too much for WinForms (and Windows in general). After running it, my Windows almost died.

So, the add control performance cannot be improved. But that should not be your main concern. Consider switching to `DataGridView` or some third party data repeater control which support a lot more number of rows w/o creating significant number of controls.